# Anyone else have sporadic problems posting answers?

Tags: support

It seems like over the last week about 1 in 10 answers I go to post error out.  It will spin for about 30-60 seconds and then goes to an empty page at:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448734/answer/submit
```

Is this issue isolated to me, or are others running into it as well?

I am using FireFox 6.0.2